# Serialization and dynamic type casting

Tags: c#, type-conversion, system.reflection

I am calling a webservice with user defined type as parameter. The following code work fine because the type casting (for objectParameter) is done with known type at the time of time of calling the service. For unknown type how to cast the object back to its original type? Is it possible to get the type information from the parameter of the method to be called and then do the conversion?

```
// web service proxy
        Service1 ser=new Service1();


        CompositeType myCompositeType=new CompositeType();
        myCompositeType.StringValue = "arjun";

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream(@"d:/MyFile.bin",
                                 FileMode.Create,
                                 FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, myCompositeType);
        stream.Close();

        IFormatter formatter1 = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream1 = new FileStream(@"d:/MyFile.bin",
                                  FileMode.Open,
                                  FileAccess.Read,
                                  FileShare.Read);

        object objectParameter= formatter1.Deserialize(stream1);

        //call to remote webservice . casting is possible because the type is known
        // it doesn't work: ser.GetDataUsingDataContract(objectParameter);
        ser.GetDataUsingDataContract((CompositeType)objectParameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check 'objectParameter' original type like this:

```
if (objectParameter is CompositeType) ser.GetDataUsingDataContract((CompositeType)objectParameter);
if (objectParameter is CompositeType2) ser.GetDataUsingDataContract((CompositeType2)objectParameter);
```

But i think that it's better to check 'objectParameter' type at service - write one base method GetDataUsingDataContract with object parameter type and inside that base method call another method by original parameter type:

```
object objectParameter= formatter1.Deserialize(stream1);
ser.GetDataUsingDataContract(objectParameter);
```

...

```
GetDataUsingDataContract(object param) {
  // calling method by original 'param' type
  if (param is CompositeType) return GetDataUsingDataContract((CompositeType)param);
  if (param is CompositeType2) return GetDataUsingDataContract((CompositeType2)param);
  return null;
}
```

Comment: You have both the known classes compositeType and compositetype2 to be type casted.what If you don't know the type infomation at all.